TabCompleter isn't working propertly - Minecraft Paper Plugin
After typing /dystrykt zapros, TabCompleter should prompt list of all online players. But in reality, TabCompleter prompts nothing.
In my code i wanted to get list of all online players but after typing /dystrykt zapros, there's nothing to tab complete.
case "zapros":
    if (player.isOp() || hasSpecialPermissions(player)) {
        for (Player onlinePlayer : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            if (!onlinePlayer.equals(player)) {
                suggestions.add(onlinePlayer.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    break;


Can you show more code? Like the full tabCompleter method

I fixed it ;) Sorry for long reply

@Slompyy if you still need help, please edit your question to include the full tabComplete method?  Thanks
